# Let $G$ be a group and $x$ an element within it. Show that if $x^2 \in CL_G(x)$ then $C_G(x)=C_G(x^2)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $x$ an element within it. Show that if $x^2 \in CL_G(x)$  then $C_G(x)=C_G(x^2)$

Notation meaning: $CL_G(x)=\{g \in G | gxg^{-1}\}$ and $C_G(x)=\{g\in G| gxg^{-1}=x\}$.

So I show that if $k \in C_G(x)$ then $k\in C_G(x^2)$, with $kxk^{-1}=x \rightarrow kx^2k^{-1}=x^2$. So we get $C_G(x) \subseteq C_G(x^2)$, but how do I show the other way around?

Thank you for any insight!

Comment: In a finite group, it's clear how to proceed ( hint: conjugate elements have conjugate centralizers). In an infinite group, I am not sure that the statement is true (it may be, I just can't see a reason at the moment)

Comment: What is $CL_G(x)$? You have write $\{g\in G : gxg^{-1}\}$ - not sure what that means.

Comment: It's the conjugacy class for $x$. @GeoffRobinson, I can't seem to see how to proceed. Can you be more elaborate?

Comment: @dsfsf : The conjugacy class of $x$ is written as $\{gxg^{-1} : g\in G\}$.

Comment: It's false in the (infinite) group defined by the presentation $\langle x,y,t \mid y^{-1}xy=x^2, t^{-1}x^2t=x^2 \rangle$. That follows from general stuff about HNN extensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that $G$ is finite, note that if $y = g^{-1}xg$, then $C_{G}(y) = g^{-1}C_{G}(x)g$ so that $C_{G}(y)$ and $C_{G}(x)$ have the same order (in the case that $G$ is infinite, they have the same cardinality). You have shown that $C_{G}(x)$ is contained in $C_{G}(x^{2}),$ so you are almost home now (when $G$ is finite).

Comment: Thank you! Why can you say that they have the same order?

Comment: Because $c \to g^{-1}cg$ is a bijection from $C_{G}(x)$ to $C_{G}(y)$.